# Data Table[Jquery Plugin] to overwrite

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the Jquery DataTables plugin.
Link:- https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html
I am able to use it properly but what I want is I need to remove the Unnecessary items that are shown in it like:- show entries,search box,previous-next buttons. I added only this in my code.
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>`

Can any one tell me how to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove Search filer and pagination add this parameters,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Datatable').dataTable( {
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false
                 } );
} );
```